# On my second call to form.Show the System.Windows.Forms.Form does not appear

Tags: winforms, compact-framework

I have gone around and around with this problem using a combination of show(), showdialog(), bringtofront() and activate().

I am running CF 3.5 on a symbol MC50 PocketPC running Windows Mobile 5 (I think it is 5...)

This has to be simpler. Could someone please please give me some advice on this one?

If I use form.Show() the second time nothing happens.
If I use form.ShowDialog() the second time I receive this error:
    "value does not fall within expected range"

Comment: What is happening to the form after the first call to Show?  Is it being closed by the user, minimized, hidden by another application, hidden by another form in your app, ...?

Comment: It is effectively being closed. I know that its closing event is being fired.

Comment: We need to see repro code.  There are a lot of possibilities.  The error makes me suspect it's something in the Form ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call form.Close(), all resources within the instance of the form and the instance itself are disposed of.  If you just wish to visually close the form but keep it around, you should use form.Hide().  This issue gave me quite a bit of frustration as well.  Below is a note from the Microsoft documentation regarding this:

> Note: 
>     When the Close method is called on a Form displayed as a modeless window,
>     you cannot call the Show method to make the form visible, because the form's
>     resources have already been released. To hide a form and then make it visible,
>     use the Control.Hide method.